Can't set Chrome's browser theme to a custom color
The older version of Google Chrome (122) on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine allowed me to set a custom color for the browser's theme using its color picker. 


But after upgrading to 123 it's not possible anymore and the color picker looks like this:



Suppose for example I want to set my browser theme to this color: #000050 which is a pure dark blue, but in the newer version it's not possible.

After some investigation I came across the file google/chrome/profile/path/Preferences and in the previous version the color is saved like this:
{
  "browser": {
    "theme": {
      "color": -14023867
    }
  }
}

but in the recent version which I don't have a sample two more keys are added and I think Chrome does something to the color I pick because in no way I could select my previous color!! So I had to downgrade, edit it, and then upgrade!
I tried even closing it, editing the color in the file, and opening it again, but seems it's being overwritten!

This is a Q&A website so please ask a question in the body. I assume you're looking for any sort of a workaround. What did you try when you manuall edited the file? Such info should always be provided.

@Destroy666 > tried even closing it, editing the color in the file, and opening it again, but seems it's being overwritten. I provided this in the question. and yes my question is how to set the color to something custom like #db5cd3

You have not provided any example of how you tried editing it. You know the file could have been overwritten due to incorrect edit, right? Not that it's the case here as Preferences files are usuall something that you shouldn't edit, but still, you should provide full details of your attempts.

@Destroy666 I exited the browser, opened the file using Vim, edited just the color code so it's not invalid (It's doing some complementing and subtraction for hex colors), saved it and opened the browser again.

What I'm saying you should provide the exact values you're editing next time. But doesn't matter here I'm pretty sure. Good luck

@Destroy666 I provided the exact path in the json snippet above, but omitted unnecessary keys and values.
